# AWS API Gateway VPC Link Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've tried to find pricing information for using the [API Gateway / VPC Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html) feature. However, I was unable to find *any* information relating to pricing of an API Gateway VPC Link.

I understand that an API Gateway VPC Link is something different than a AWS PrivateLink VPC endpoint. The latter allows access to AWS services over a private connection (so not over the internet) whereas the former (what I want) allows accessing VPC-internal resources (such as HTTP endpoints) from a (public) API Gateway API.

The [AWS API Gateway Pricing site](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/) does not mention the VPC Link feature anywhere. It only mentions PrivateLink when using private APIs that are only internally visible inside the VPC (which is *not* what I want). I want to use API Gateway VPC Link to allow a *public* API access to VPC-internal resources.

So the question is: Does using an API Gateway VPC Link entail *any* costs (uptime / network I/O?).

Guess-work from here on:

A hint that it may probably not cost much or anything at all is this AWS blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-integrating-http-apis-with-aws-cloud-map-and-amazon-ecs-services/ which is actually my use-case here: Avoiding ALB costs for routing HTTP calls to Lambda and ECS service by making use of API Gateway VPC Link together with CloudMap ECS service registration. In this blog article, AWS mentions

> Initial estimates for RS Component’ configuration based on a single instance Application Load Balancer based environment would cost approximately $25, a AWS Cloud Map equivalent would be under $5 per month.

which does sound like RS Components previously only payed maybe `USD 23.36` (`0.032` per hour times 730 hours in a month) for the ALB (us-east-1 price) plus the `USD 0.5` for a Route53 hosted zone compared to `USD 5` for (maybe?) a few [Cloud Map resources](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/pricing/).

Comment: Looks like it's free.